# Robocopy mirror when source files have moved directory

Tags: windows, backup, robocopy

so I'm using RoboCopy to mirror source and destination. It mirrors fine, so now I have matching content on Source A: and Destination B:.

My question is this. If I take all files and subfolders from Source A: and move it into a new directory, like so: A:\NewDIR, and I run the mirror command against Destination B:, it seems that it is basically doing the whole copy process all over again, when what I really want is some way for it to know that all of the files have just moved directory. So instead of copying everything over from new to B:\NewDir and then delete everything else outside NewDir - which seems really inefficient - I would like to just Create the A:\NewDir folder and move the files, which should complete in no time.

Is there any way to accomplish this? Do I need some sort of reference file list or hash comparison?

Thx,
Alex

Comment: Did you *move* the files to NewDIR, or did you *copy* them? These two operations are not identical.

Comment: I moved them; just to test the behavior. I created the new DIR and moved everything into there.

Comment: Then you should move everything on destination B: as well. Then restart your mirror process which will then see all files on the source and destination are in the same location.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with `robocopy`.

You need a backup/sync program that scans both A and B in full (and then identifies any moved files or folders) *before* doing anything else. In comparison, robocopy works on a folder basis - it scans current folder on both sides, rectifies any differences, moves on to the next folder. So it cannot detect moves in principle.